# Mail Format in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

In Web application, I'm trying to send mail to the user with an attachment, I'm sending mail to user but it is not in a good format this is my mail format which is written in asp.net.

```
 StringBuilder stbldr =new StringBuilder();
         stbldr.Append("<html><body>
        <a href='http://*****/xyxi/mycheck/CheckAttachment.aspx?attid=" + s + "&Eid=" + t + "&afile=" + attach+ "' target='_blank'>Attachment..</a> " + cnt + " <br>
        </body> </html>");
```

when mail send to user, the format in mail is same like above, it is displaying in all tags also  like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
message.Body = stbldr.ToString();
message.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Html;
message.From = txtemail.Text;
message.To = "xxx";
message.Subject = "test";
SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "sxxxxt";
SmtpMail.Send(message);
```

specify body format as html